# cfdocument inner html rendering at wrong scale

Tags: coldfusion, stylesheet, styles, cfdocument

CF Version: 7,0,2,142559

```
<cfdocument pageheight="11" 
            pagewidth="8.5" 
            unit="in" 
            marginbottom=".7" 
            marginleft="0" 
            marginright="0" 
            margintop="1.1" 
            format="pdf" 
            pagetype="custom" 
            scale="100">
```

I have a

```
<cfdocumentitem type="header">
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">@import "header.css";</style>
  <div class=header>
    Content
  </div>
<cfdocumentitem>
```

header.css looks like

```
#top {
position:absolute;
left:0in;
top:0in;
height:.458in;
width:8.5in;
background-color:#770000;
}
```

also have a similar footer

Then inside the cfdocument tag I have

```
<div id="content" 
     style="position:absolute; 
            left:0in; top:0in; 
            width:7in; 
            border:solid; 
            border-width:thin;">
```

The problem is the content div is rendering wider than the header and footer, it looks like it's out of scale or something. If I reduce the width of the "content" div in a guess and check kind of way, it seems that as soon as I hit a width that would match the width of the header and footer it snaps back into normal scale and won't fit the width like I need it to. How can I fix this?

Annoying thing is I can style the content div to width:6.51in;height:6.95in; and it fits perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in CFMX 7.
Check these links and make sure you update your server.

[Coldfusion MX 7 Hot Fixes](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/402/kb402465.html)
[ColdFusion MX 7 CFDocument Hotfix](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/402/kb402093.html)

Comment: Thanks, Having my sys admin check if those are installed or not.

Comment: According to our sys admin, we already have those updates installed. Thanks though.

Comment: Have you tried this on another version of CF?  Which version of Java is CF running on?  I believe java 1.4 had problems with pdf generation.